# Ansible. How to save result of find of finder path

Tags: loops, ansible, path, find

I try to replace the word in `/some_dir/*some_patterns*/*.file` .
I have an ERROR when read a `rsl2`. It because the `rsl2` has other structure of the `rsl`.

```yaml
- name: "find folder with some_patterns in some_dir"
  find: 
    paths: /some_dir
    patterns: "*some_patterns*" 
    file_type: "directory"
  register: rsl

- name: "find folder with some_patterns2 in dir2"
  find: 
    paths: "{{ item.path }}/dir2" 
    patterns: "*.file"
  register: rsl2
  loop: "{{ rsl.files }}"

- name: "replace word"
  replace:
    dest: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: 'word'
    replace: 'new_word'
  loop: "{{ rsl2.files }}"
```

I try to save via variable but I have massive in massive [[][]]

Comment: "_but I have massive in massive `[[][]]`_" and which are just Nested Lists.

Comment: But i can't parse lists in this list.

Comment: Please read [ask] and pay attention to [mre] section. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```yaml
- name: "find folder with some_patterns in some_dir"
  find: 
    paths: /some_dir
    patterns: "*some_patterns*" 
    file_type: "directory"
  register: rsl

- name: "find folder with some_patterns2 in dir2"
  find: 
    paths: "{{ item.path }}/Desktop" 
    patterns: "*.file"
  loop: "{{ rsl.files }}"
  register: rsl2

- name: "create empty file_path_arr"
  set_fact:
    file_path_arr: "{{ [] }}"

- name: "append to file_path_arr"
  set_fact:
    file_path_arr: "{{ file_path_arr + item.files }}"
  loop: "{{ rsl2.results }}"

- name: "replace word"
  replace:
    dest: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: 'word'
    replace: 'new_word'
  loop: "{{ file_path_arr }}"
```